Visual Studio 2022 Folder Publish Doesn't Copy Unchanged Files
I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 project that I recently branched to work on major performance updates. I published breaking changes to my dev environment while testing various changes.
Once I was done testing, I needed to return the dev server back to the primary branch. I loaded the trunk solution and published, but was surprised to see some of my changes still in place after refreshing.
I cleared my cache and tried again, but found the same. I examined the JavaScript files on the server and, sure enough, they still contain changes from the branch. I then checked the contents of {trunk source location}\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp to make sure that the JavaScript files were there and that they contained the correct code for the trunk. They did.
I tried publishing several times with no change. It wasn't until I went into the JavaScript files, made a whitespace change, and saved the files, that they finally published properly. This seems dangerous and wrong.
How can I tell which files weren't published as expected? Do I need to manually make a whitespace change to all of them to return the server to the stable trunk branch? I expect all files to publish regardless of whether they have changes. We rely on TFS Pipelines and Releases to publish to our other servers. Would they be affected by this behavior as well?
I guess my real question is: is there some way I can tell VS to always publish all files, regardless of change status?
Info that might be relevant:

Both branches are built using the Debug configuration
They are being deployed using the "Folder Publish Profile"
The folder path is a UNC network share path (e.g. \\myserver\drive$\path\to\folder)
The "Delete existing files" option is disabled
The "Precompile during publishing" option is disabled
The "Exclude files from the App_Data folder" option is disabled

